# RESTFUL routing with the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking to find the best way to setup the routes for my app.

The application allows users to register, post jobs and apply for jobs. The issue I am having is that two routes that should really show different things are linking through to the same pages.

My routes are as follows:

```
 resources :users do
   resources :apps
 end

 resources :jobs do
   resources :apps
 end
```

As a result of this I end up with two paths:

```
users/id/apps
jobs/id/apps
```

What I would like to do is use the first path to show job applications that a user has completed. I would then like to use the second path to show the owner of the job the applications they have received for that job.

The issue I am having is that both paths end up at `apps#index`

Any advice people can offer on how to best route this would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those paths are potentially fine for what you want to do.  When a request comes into

`users/:user_id/apps`

then you'll be able to do something like this in your controller to populate the list of apps:

```
@apps = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).apps
```

And in the case of the other path, you'll do the same but with `params[:jobs_id]`, e.g.

```
@apps = Job.find_by_id(params[:job_id]).apps
```

In your controller you would have some conditional code that builds @apps depending on which path the request came in via (by looking to see if :user_id or :job_id is in params)... something like this:

```
if params[:user_id]
    @apps = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).apps
elsif params[:job_id]
    @apps = Job.find_by_id(params[:job_id]).apps
end
```

or maybe refactored to...

```
if params[:user_id]
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @apps = @user.apps
elsif params[:job_id]
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @apps = @job.apps
end
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your reply, this is very helpful. It would be great if you could provide an example of how I would check the params of the incoming request. I am guessing it would be some kind of `ifels` statement but am unsure how I would construct it? thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "resources" keyword, rails will just map to the default routes.
If you would like specific routes to map to something else, you should consider using "match."
For example:

```
match "users/id/apps" => "users/id/apps"
match "jobs/id/owners" => "jobs/id/owners"
```

This page shows a more detailed usage of it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
You also have the options to change the route to something else or the code itself.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Linx, on this occassion I think being able to define it in the controller is best just because I am trying to be as 'restful' as possible. This is still very useful though! :)